# Looking for the equivalent of a SQL-statement for Power BI

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am looking for the possibility to display all information in a table for the value of column HistID by giving an input of another column (PropertyValue), similar to the SQL statement below.

```
select * 
from EventHistory
where HistID in (
               select HistID 
               from EventHistory
               where PropertyValue = '10048')
```

The value of 10048 should be put in with a textfilter in PowerBI.

Is it possible to display this in PowerBI?

Answer (score 0):

- Import the EventHistory table into Power BI.
- Add the HistID and PropertyValue columns to a new table visual.
- Click on the PropertyValue column in the visual and select "Text Filters" > "Equals".
- Enter "10048" as the filter value and click "OK".
- The table visual will now display all information in a table for the value of column HistID that matches the PropertyValue input.